# How to add custom colors once the editor has initialized

Tags: javascript, html, quill

As the title is saying, is there anyway to add colors post init on `quill`? I have access to the editor variable.

```
    var Colors = ['black','white];
    // ...
    var TOOLBAR_CONFIG = [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'link', { 'color': Colors }, { 'list': 'bullet' },
        { header: 1 }, { header: 2 }, 'image'
    ]];

    QuillEditor = new Quill('#'+this.props.id, {
        bounds: '.cnt',
        theme: 'bubble',
        modules: {
            toolbar: TOOLBAR_CONFIG
        }
    });
    // ...
    // Somewhere else in a action listen i would like to add a custom color, e.g:
    myhandle(){
        Colors.push('blue');
        // I tried looking at QuillEditor.getModule('toolbar'); but could not see any event?
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to Destroy by `quill.destroy();` and reinitialize quill editor.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor');
quill.addModule('toolbar', { container: '#toolbar' });

$('#destroyAndInit').click(function() {
  quill.destroy();
  $(".ql-color").append("<option value='rgb(255,0,0)'>red</option>");
 quill = new Quill('#editor');
    quill.addModule('toolbar', { container: '#toolbar' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-quill/0.4.1/quill.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Create the toolbar container -->
<div id="toolbar">
    <select class="ql-color">
        <option value="rgb(0, 102, 204)">blue</option>
        <option value="rgb(0,255,0)">green</option>
        <option value="rgb(0,0,0)" selected>black</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="destroyAndInit">Add red color</button>

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <div>Select me to change color!</div>
  <div>Select me and choose color to change my color.</div>
  <div><br></div>
</div>
    
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/0.20.1/quill.js"></script>
```

Comment: Quill no longer has the `destroy()` method for those coming here now

Answer (score 2):

According to the official website you could add colors when initializing the editor:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }, {color: ['red', 'blue']}],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
  ]
},
placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
```

});

As you can see while instance is being initialized you could pass the colors as an array to the toolbars.